# Archive binary has reversed hex signature

Tags: linux, compression, archiving, xxd

## Context

This is a repost of my StackOverflow question which was incorrectly asked, as it does not relate to programming.

I'm playing Bandit on OverTheWire, and [level thirteen](https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit13.html) requires unzipping various compressed file formats without knowing the file extension. To do this, I have been comparing the hexdump with file signatures from [Gary Kessler's website](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html).

What I've noticed however is that the hex signature appears backwards. For example, take this `gz, tgz gzip` archive file:

```
0000000 8b1f 0808 5006 5eb4 0302 6164 6174 2e32
0000010 6962 006e 3d01 c202 42fd 685a 3139 5941
0000020 5326 8e59 1c4f 00c8 1e00 ff7f f9fb da7f
...
```

With the signature `8b1f 0808` is backwards, as compared to what Gary Kessler's website indicates:

```
1F 8B 08        .‹. GZ, TGZ         GZIP archive file
                        VLT         VLC Player Skin file
```

## Question

Why is the signature backwards? `1F 8B 08` vs `8b1f 0808`. The first file encountered is a hexdump of an archive file, `data.txt`, and has a proper signature of `1f8b 0808` (found using `head data.txt`), which aligns perfectly with the signature. However, when I run `xxd -r data.txt | hexdump` I once again `8b1f 0808`.

The comments on my StackOverflow question seem to indicate that it's related to big / little endianess, and pointed me towards the `-g1` flag of `xxd`, which stands for grouping.

This does provide the right output but I don't understand what grouping is or how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping in `xxd` refers to the number of bytes that are treated (and displayed) as a unit.

By default, `xxd` treats its input as groups of 2 bytes / 16 bits (a four digit hexadecimal number) stored in big-endian order.

This will have the effect that every group of two bytes from the input will be displayed in reversed order (but actually the correct order for a big-endian system).

I.e. the first two bytes from the input `18 8B` will become one 16-bit number `8B18`, which is exactly what you see.

When you change the `xxd` grouping to "1" with the option `-g1`, all bytes from the input will be interpreted as single-byte numbers (which obviously do not have an "endian-ness") and will be displayed in the order they are read from the input.